# NSPredicate for property of object in NSArray of NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an objects like the below structure: Transaction has an array of Items. Item has an array of SubItems

```
@interface Transaction : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *id; 
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger status;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items; // array of Item
@end

@interface Item : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *subitems;
@end


@interface SubItem : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger price;
@end
```

I would like to create predicate to find *name* and *price* of **Subitem** from **NSArray of Transaction**

```
pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                    @"ANY SELF.%K.%K.%K contains %@",
                    @"items",
                    @"subitems",
                    @"name",
                    @"MY_SUB_ITEM_NAME"];
```

This generates the error below.

> failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "Can't do regex matching
>   on object (
>       MY_SUB_ITEM_NAME )."

However when I use the similar format to find out properties in Transaction. It works fine.

```
 pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                    @"SELF.%K LIKE %@",
                    @"identifier",
                    @"TX001"];
```

How should I correct my predicate to query property in **Item** and **SubItem**

Comment: What is id and "MY_SUB_ITEM_NAME"? I am not find any field in subitems like id

Comment: `My_SUB_ITEM_NAME` is the value to compare against. It has nothing to do with the properties.

Comment: Sorry about my wrongIy type 'id'. It should be 'name'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that cannot work with `-predicateWithFormat:` for two aggregation levels. On *each* level you can have a `ANY` or an `ALL` aggregation. So the "right" syntax would be `ANY items ANY subitems.… = …`. Or `ANY items ALL subitems.…= …"` or …

You can try to build the predicate manually with `NSExpression`, probably using subqueries.

Oh, you are not using Core Data, what I assumed. So simply do it manually in a loop or use a computed property.